# Firefox and IE aren't displaying "<script ... > ... </script>" provided from PHP

Tags: php, firefox, internet-explorer

Hey everyone, I am having a problem with a website I'm trying to build; basically I have a class that I call from my header file that loads all of the link and script tags.  The link tags show up across all browsers, but the script tags only show up in safari and chrome, they do no show up in firefox or IE.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='...'>
```

now I have tried removing the "<" at the front of the tag just to see what happens, and it will show up as plain text then, but as soon as I put the "<" back it is again MIA.

So here is what's going on in the php. My **header.php** file calls the cms object function, located in **cms.php**, and those functions call other functions in my **system.php** file.

Now, again the link tags work w/out a hitch and I call them the exact same way ... it is just the dumb script tags.  When I call the load_js("config"); function in my header.php it will load multiple tags as well.  If it was just 1 tag I would put the script tags in the html rather than in the php, but I don't think I can do that when I'm producing multiple tags.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance as well!

### header.php

```
<?php echo $this->load_css("config"); ?>  
<?php echo $this->load_js("config"); ?>
```

### cms.php

```
function load_js($name){        
    // ...
    return header_script($name.".js");
    // ...
}
function load_css($name){       
    // ...
    return header_link($name.".css");
    // ...
}
```

### system.php

```
function header_script(){
    // 0 = src
    $num = func_num_args();
    if($num == 0){
        return;// if no arguments, can't successfully build header_script.
    }
    if($num == 1){
        return "<script type='application/javascript' src='".func_get_arg(0)."'></script>\n";
    }
}
function header_link(){
    $num = func_num_args();
    // 0 = rel
    // 1 = type
    // 2 = href
    if($num < 3){
        return; // can't successfully build link.
    }
    if($num == 3){
        return "<link rel='".func_get_arg(0)."' type ='".func_get_arg(1)."' href='".func_get_arg(2)."' />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact, generated HTML code that gets issued in your browser please, including the full path? The whole `head` section would be perfect.

Comment: From the limited code that you've provided, it looks like you're hitting the if($num == 0) case in header_script. Are there any other lines where that function is called?

Comment: @allyourcode why? `num` is the number of arguments passed to the function. He is passing an argument in the header.php call

Comment: What the hell is going on here?  Since when did formal parameters jump the shark?

Comment: @Justin true, it's very unorthodox. And difficult to look up in an IDE, which is why I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @Pekka: me neither, unless the function is documented with proper PHPDoc `@param` tags

Comment: thanks for all of your replies, @allyourcode I'm not hitting the $num == 0 cause I am passing arguments. I should be using parameters on this function but due to previous options I needed a dynamic amount of parameters ... but I removed that option and am only using the 1 parameter so I will change it to have a default value as suggested.

I am unable to test the answer posted by webbiedave yet cause apparently it is only windows based firefox and of course IE that isn't displaying the script tags.  I tried it on a mac without changes and it worked fine.

Comment: @Pekka and @stmpy: There is alot of code that's not shown. It could very well be that it's being called with zero args somewhere else.

Comment: @stmpy what exactly do you mean by "script tags are not shown." Do you mean they are physically missing in your "view source" source code?

Comment: @allyourcode I agree that this is the most likely culprit, but his header.php (which is the part of the code that doesn't work) shows that there is an argument.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to use default argument values in situations like this where you have a set order and a maximum amount of formal parameters. Example: function header_link($rel="", $type="", $href="") {
 if ( !empty($rel) && !empty($type) && !empty($href) {
  return  "<link rel='{$rel}' type ='{$type}' href='{$href}' />\n";
 }
}

Comment: @allyourcode Part of the code I removed was echo tags displaying the amount of arguments being passed. But I didn't see that relevant to this post (to remove confusion), but as answered below, my problem was the type.

@Justin Johnson, you are right, it is perfectly reasonable to use arguments (For clarity, etc ...) I have been changing this code like mad trying to get it to work lately and I will use your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `application/javascript` is not recognized by some browsers. You should change that to `text/javascript`

Secondly, as mentioned in comments (Justin Johnson), you should use parameters in your function definition with default values:

```
function header_script($name = '')
{
    if ($name != '') {
        return '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$name.'"</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Single quotes around attribute values are, in fact, valid HTML, per the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: @webbiedave not if his problem is that the actual script tags do not appear in IE and FF. The OP is a bit hazy on this, though.

Comment: @Pekka: That the OP did not mention that the PHP checked the agent string and behaved differently depending on that, I surmised that the same html is sent for each request, regardless of browser. Because of that, the bad `type` became a primary suspect.

Comment: when I said that the script tags don't show up I mean when you look at the source of the site they are completely missing.  There are line breaks from the '\n' but the <script ...>...</script> tags are not there.  

Also when I remove the first "<" and only have "script ...>...</script>" then the tag will show up but now that it isn't recognized as a tag it is shown as plain text.

Comment: I wasn't able to test this solution till today cause I don't have a windows computer at home, but I just tested it and it works, all I had to do was change the type to text/javascript!  Thank you everyone for your suggestions, and for the advice.